# How to prevent scrolling down a controlled textarea when value changes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux, controlled-component

I have a long textarea, with 100-200 lines. 
They corresponds to redux state `phrases = [{id, text, ...}]`, each line of textarea is a phrases[id].text.

```
<textarea value={_.map(phrases, 'text').join('\n')}></textarea>
```

When I change textarea, it dispatches change of redux state `phrases`.

And when I change one letter from first line, page scrolls to end and cursor goes to 200th line. But I want that cursor and scroll position of page doesn't change.

I tried to use event.target.selectionStart, selectionEnd, but even cursor returns on its position, page scrolls to the screen end.

How to fix it?

[image: image for example]

Comment: I've created [simple demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-sunset-7w7bn) where value is set randomly by timer. it does not scroll to the end to me. probably you component is recreated instead of being updated(but then it would scroll to top, not to bottom). make some minimal example to reproduce.

Comment: @skyboyer, can you look at my [app](https://frazy.me/material/edit/wTYrWljgxVprZzxQqaQo/ru), and [code](https://github.com/Aparus/frazy/blob/master/src/components/materialForm/MaterialFormPhrases.jsx) please?

Comment: hard to say, I edited text in both textareas and page was not scrolled down to me.

Comment: @skyboyer, now I see, it happens only when I add new line. thank you for answer